# Problem with transform.rotation in unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I`ve been doing a game and i got a problem , i tried to do a jumping cube but if you jump a lot the cube can rotate , i tried to restrict rotation by using:

```
// Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Transform.rotation = 0f);
        {
            Transform.position = new Vector3(0,0,0);
        }
        else ();
        {
            Transform.rotation = new Vector3(0,0,0);
        }
    }
```

but i just get an error , i don`t know why because i did the same thing with the position and it was fine , so is there a solution?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I suggest you read about the [essential Unity classes] (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptingImportantClasses.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is because position is a [Vector3](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html) and Rotation is a [Quaternion](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html)!
This code is also probably not going to achieve what you'd like.

Something like this uses the correct syntax:

```
void Update()
    {
        if (Transform.rotation == Quaternion.identity);
        {
            Transform.position = new Vector3(0,0,0);
        }
        else;
        {
            Transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
        }
    }
```

But this is still going to give you very strange behaviour.
I'd encourage you to use [RigidBody constraints](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-constraints.html) instead.
It would also help to practice c# syntax and logic first. Good luck